# Manually open and close connection with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, connection, explicit

I have been searching the web since yesterday but cannot find an example which may solve my issue.

I am trying open and close the connection manually with the below code

```
        Using conn = New EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString)

            Using ctx As New EbosEntities()

                 conn.Open()
```

The problem is, how do i write a constructor(Entity Class) which will take the conn as parameter? otherwise this connection will have nothing to do with the (new context) declaration, I guess. Like below,

```
           ctx As New EbosEntities(conn)
```

If I want to use default connection string can I just write

```
           ctx.Database.Connection.Open()
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do it on VB, but with C# you can try to do something like this:

```
    var datacontext = new EbosEntities();
    try
    {                
        datacontext.Connection.Open();
        //do some work

    }
    finally
    {
        datacontext.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, what is the difference between conn.Open() and ctx.Database.Connection.Open().